# display remote value in from json associative array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I display the members.Rating for "Jones, Jim"? I have tried the syntax: echo members[$temp].Rating but it doesn't work.

```
let $temp = "Jones, Jim";

var members = [ 

{ "Rating": "1500", "Name": "Williams, Bill"}, 
{ "Rating": "2000", "Name": "Smith, Paul" }, 
{ "Rating": "1000", "Name": "Jones, Jim" }, 
{ "Rating": "1750", "Name": "Reynolds, Beverly" } ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
let $temp = "Jones, Jim";

var members = [ 

{ "Rating": "1500", "Name": "Williams, Bill"}, 
{ "Rating": "2000", "Name": "Smith, Paul" }, 
{ "Rating": "1000", "Name": "Jones, Jim" }, 
{ "Rating": "1750", "Name": "Reynolds, Beverly" } ]

console.log(
  members.find(x => x.Name === $temp).Rating
)
```

Comment: Splendid! Much appreciated!

Comment: this is not a safe approach. if `$temp` isn't found in the array, this approach will throw a `TypeError`. the easiest fix would be: `(members.find(x => x.Name === $temp) || {}).Rating`, which will return `undefined` instead of throwing an error.

Comment: @Brandon Yes. OP needs to handle exception accordingly when using this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly reference a member of an array by value, only by index.

So, you'll have to use the `find` method, like so:

```
const tempMember = members.find(p => p.Name === $temp)
const tempMemberRating= tempMember && tempMember.Rating
```

Note that if `find` doesn't find the element you want, it will return `undefined`. This makes the mult-line approach necessary, as simply calling it all in one line could result in a `TypeError`. e.g.:

```
members.find(p => p.Name === "Johnson, Jimmy").Rating
```

Since `find` returns `undefined` here, you're attempting to reference `undefined.Rating`, which will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
For (var i=0 ;i <members.length ;i++){

      If ( members[i].Name == $temp ){

            console.log (members[i].Raiting);
       }

 }
```